# Azure data flow string to date conversion in formate

Tags: azure, t-sql, to-date, azure-data-factory

My source is CSV contains enddate & startdate column datype string. I need to change those date columns in destination table format.

source -

[image]

Destination :

```
SALES_ORGANIZATION  STARTDATE   ENDDATE EXTRACT_MNTS
AE93-AE-CS  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  4
AE93-AE-CS  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  4
AE93-AE-CS  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  4
AE93-AE-CS  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  4
```

I am using data flow :
[image]
END
Enddate is not coming as excepted :
[image]

What is the way I already check todate(ENDDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') this is giving NULL.

Comment: Have you considered a staging table on the database where you dump the CSV contents as they are and THEN do the manipulation? ELT is far easier (and generally better performing) than ETL.

Comment: Hi you are saying to load csv in one stg table and that stg table I can choose as a source in data flow ? Am I understanding correcting?

Comment: Well ideally, you would then write a stored procedure to load from the stg table to the dst table and call that sproc in the data flow. The least amount of transformation you can do outside of the DB the better. The sproc method also means you don't have to modify your azure data factory to change logic, you just update the sproc.

Comment: I am stuck while copying the data from blob to stg table, I have 5 date columns out of which one date column have NULL while copying to sink synpase with datatype date it is throwing a error for datatype conversion failed NUll would not allow in date column. The same issue I am facing in data flow also.

Comment: don't use datatypes in stage table, make everything string (NVARCHAR)

Comment: Also, if it's saying NULL isn't allowed, then just don't make the column NOT NULL.

Comment: Hi Anthony it is working for me I have created a table with nvarchar & refred that stg table as a source in mine dataflow after that alter table upsert then sink as a core table. It is working without using derived column transformation. Still My question is not answered how we can achieve it directly from data flow without stg table concept.

Comment: honestly, you just shouldn't do it in the data flow. It's going to be a lot slower both in processing time and development (see how easy it was to do the stg table vs the data flow).

Comment: One more question flow -----copy activity -- then Mapping data flow (--- stg table my source -- upsert ok key column -- sink on the core table.) so dataflow I am using for upsert it is fine or store procedure way I have to go ??

Comment: Stored procedure has a lot of benefits. You don't have to go into your Azure project if you need to mod the code, it has proc caching, more accessible to other people, etc. You CAN do whatever you want, but sproc usually has more value.

Comment: Hi Anthony yup from starting Sp / CTAS in synpase we can write but just to reduce the coding efforts I think for a mapping data flow. I am not sure if still we need to go by old sp traditional way they I am in dilemma what's the use of data flow in adf?

Comment: ADF and it's precursor SSIS are very good for workflow organization and getting data (as is) from point A to point B. They are not very good for manipulating that data in flight though, so that's why you tend to leave that to the DB

Comment: Hi Anthony yes that correct I have implemented the ELT logic & it is working fine. Thanks for your quick reply. Your inputs is valuable for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `toDate()` condition inside `iifNull()` condition and it will work fine. Also, make sure that `MM` in date format should be in upper case.

Eg: `iifNull(toDate(start, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), toDate(start, 'dd-MM-yyyy'))`

Find the snippets below.

**Source data preview:**
[image]

**Derived column data preview:**
[image]